# Dynamics AX 2009 - Modify insert into smmActivities from ProjTableWizard?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am an AX newbie, and I need to make a modification to the ProjTableWizard form code and have not been able to locate where I need to make the change. Essentially what I need to do is modify the part of the Wizard process when creating a sub-project. I need to figure out how a line is inserted into the smmActivities table, so that I can modify the “Activity Purpose” field (prefix it with the Activity Purpose of its parent Project from the ProjTable Form) following the “Finish” button click on the ProjTableWizard form. So far I have been unable to figure out how the ProjTableWizard form is triggering this insert into smmActivities (and how the Purpose field is being populated from the Wizard). Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To locate the code that is creating `smmActivities` records, set a breakpoint in the `smmActivities.insert()` method, then run the `ProjTableWizard`. Once the debugger pops up, you can view the stack trace to see where the insert was called from.

When using the `ProjTableWizard` to create a project from a template, the `smmActivities` records are created in the class method `HierarchyTemplateCopying.copyActivity()`. It looks like the `Purpose` field is simply copied from the `smmActivities` records associated with the template.